# Why would people delete a historical question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler/1672#1672) has been deleted for some reason.

While it make sense to remove off-topic question at this time it makes no sense to remove a very popular question.

I thought that some old questions could stay because of historical reason.

I mean the question I'm linked is a great reference (hundreds of upvotes), not only did I favorited it, I also bookmarked it, so I was surprised to see it deleted.

Comment: I'm split on this. On one hand, it looks like a historical lock would be appropriate, on the other we should validate all the links in the answers before doing so, and we won't be able to fix link rot afterwards.

Comment: Well it was an active wiki where the last edit was on June 28, I didnt notice any broken link yet

Comment: Because Robert forgot to select "permanent" from the drop-down when he locked the question last time.

Comment: asked 5 years ago and   viewed 167710 times .. **favorited by 1423** users ... i think this kind of question should be locked instead deleting

Comment: @animuson, I failed to notice Robert also reverted Tim's historical lock. Even the moderators seem to be split about this.

Comment: The activity was pretty spotty. There was a 2.5 year gap where no one updated it at all. Many of those links are just to Amazon. I don't think that's a stellar resource, but I don't think the links are likely to rot either. It would probably be better to move this information to the [compiler] tag wiki.